# ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: java, javascript, performance, database-performance

I had a major issue with application server (Hanged) and identified that the DB Server CPU utilization reached to 100% and found the below errors in application server log files. Please let me know how to find the root cause for this issue. I'm a new newbie and struggling to analyze the logs so any help would be highly appreciated.

```
2014-11-26 10:39:29,634 [EventsDispatcherWorker-1] DEBUG (ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:216) - updateEvents: got [2] events.
2014-11-26 10:39:29,636 [EventsDispatcherWorker-1] ERROR (ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:255) - could not update request [com.nolio.platform.shared.datamodel.execution.events.HealthStaticInfoDTO@34f1c59c].

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
        at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.event.spi.LoadEvent.<init>(LoadEvent.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2422)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
        at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.healthCheck.HealthCheckDao.setStaticInfo(HealthCheckDao.java:144)
        at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.healthCheck.HealthCheckPersistencyServiceImpl.onDataReceived(HealthCheckPersistencyServiceImpl.java:107)
        at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.healthCheck.HealthCheckServiceImpl.addMonitoringData(HealthCheckServiceImpl.java:301)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor621.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at 

org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy148.addMonitoringData(Unknown Source)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.execution.ExecutionEventServiceImpl.saveEventsToDatabase(ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:248)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.execution.ExecutionEventServiceImpl.access$500(ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:99)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.execution.ExecutionEventServiceImpl$DispatcherTask.updateSingleExecutionServerEvents(ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:775)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.execution.ExecutionEventServiceImpl$DispatcherTask.run(ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:728)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-11-26 10:39:29,646 [EventsDispatcherWorker-1] INFO  (ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:262) - took 0 msec to persist 0 step events
2014-11-26 10:39:29,647 [EventsDispatcherWorker-1] DEBUG (ExecutionEventServiceImpl.java:268) - updateEvents:: finish receiving events. update events took [12] milliseconds
2014-11-26 10:39:30,114 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG (RCRCReportsServiceImpl.java:223) - filtering...


2014-11-26 10:48:38,447 [http-nio-8080-exec-94] ERROR (ControllerBase.java:51) - Controller method error occurred.
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.flush(Utf8Generator.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1347)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.GWTCacheFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheFilter.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.ha.MasterNacIdentifierInterceptor.doFilter(MasterNacIdentifierInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at com.nolio.platform.server.dataservices.services.auth.NolioRunAsFilter.doFilter(NolioRunAsFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:94)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:163)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:242)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer.flush(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:94)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:793)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:359)
    ... 71 more
2014-11-26 10:48:38,450 [http-nio-8080-exec-94] ERROR (ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:278) - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: private com.nolio.liquor.dtos.errors.release.ErrorsListDto com.nolio.releasecenter.controllers.ControllerBase.handleException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:101)
```

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading" would be the first exception I would try to tackle. This simply shows incorrect use of the api function. You are not passing in the required id to load.

Comment: Please paste a little bit of code ... But typically you try to load an hibernate object without (correct) ID